# javascript call to a wcf service

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have made a WCF REST service which returns the response in JSON format and now I want to
    call it from javascript.But when I try to call it I couldn't view any response.
    To make a javascript call I have written this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Greeting() {
    $("#btnWCFREST").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8732/Services/RoleService/json/Role/provider",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            successs: function(msg) {
                         alert(msg);
            },
            Error: function(msg) {
                      alert("Failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I get the response. Where Am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error - you never close you `click` method call's parentheses:

```
        }); // end .ajax function
    } // // end .click function - should be });
} // end Greeting function declaration
```

Also, `Error:` should be `error:` (JavaScript is case-sensitive).

Comment: I made ur above said changes and running  the application.But when I check in developerTools Console window I got error like this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) 

http://localhost:8732/IServices/RoleService/json/Role/provider

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:/http://localhost:8732/IServices/RoleService/json/Role/provider 
Origin http://localhost:3098 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: @cutiepie - you are serving your page and your web service off of different ports - that means that it is cross-domain as far as the browser is concerned.  Either serve them both off the same port or have your web service send out a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that allows access from the `domain:port` that your JavaScript is on.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `s` in `successs`. Change it to `success` to get that function to work.

Also, you used an uppercase `E` in `Error`. I believe Javascript is case-sensitive, so you will probably need to change that to `error` (all lowercase).

The first parameter passed into the error function will be the jqXHR object and the *second* parameter is the error message. So if you actually want to get the error message (which you may not, since you aren't using it), then you will need to add another parameter to your `error` function.

Finally, as @SeanVieira pointed out, you are missing a closing parenthesis for your `click` function.